# let X be U(a,b) show E(x) = (a+b)/2

Tags: measure-theory

Given that $X \ is \   U(a,b)$ and measurable on $(\Omega,F,P)$ we are asked to prove $E(X) = \frac{a+b}{2}$.  I've attempted this with simple functions by defining X as follows:

X = $\sum_i x_iI_{X_i}$ and thus E(X) = $\sum_i x_i P(X_i)$ but I'm unclear on the value of $P(X_i)$ since if F is B(R) on $\Omega = (a,b)$ isn't the length of each $P(X_i) = 0 $ as per its Lebesgue measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X]&=\int_{\Omega}Xd\mathbb{P}=\int_{a}^{b}x\mathcal{L}_{X}(dx)\\
 &=\int_{a}^{b}x\frac{dx}{b-a}=\frac{a+b}{2}
\end{align}